# Entity Framework 4.3 to Oracle: Web project works, NUnit doesn't

Tags: entity-framework

I've set up Entity Framework 4.3 against an Oracle database using DevArt's provider.  I'm having a problem connecting to the database though through my unit test project in the NUnit 2.6 test runner.  The funny thing is, I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 project connecting to it just fine.  I've created an App.config in my class library unit test project and copied the entity connection string info to it.  What am I missing?

Here's the entity connection info (same in Web.config and App.config):

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.MagellanDataModel.csdl|res://*/Entities.MagellanDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Entities.MagellanDataModel.msl;provider=Devart.Data.Oracle;provider connection string=&quot;User Id=theusername;Password=thepassword;Server=theTNSname&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Here's the exception info:

```
AppName.Tests.AccountRepositoryTests.GetByContactId:
System.Data.EntityException : The underlying provider failed on Open.
----> System.InvalidOperationException : Can not obtain Oracle client information
      from registry. Make sure that Oracle Client Software is installed, or use 
      Direct mode of connecting to server.
```

NOTE: Both the web and unit test assemblies are set to compile to `Any CPU`.  I'm running 32 bit Oracle 10g database on 64 bit Windows 7.  I found a post seems to indicate that it's related to the Platform needing to be x86, but my web project is set to `Any CPU` and it's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem: Win7 64-bit DevArt with 32bit Oracle.

Works well with `Any CPU` for web projects but fails for console and unit tests projects. I fixed it *(or work around it)* by setting `x86` for tests and console projs in `Debug` mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me this problem is resolved by unchecking 'Prefer 32-bit' check box in Project properties -> Build -> below Platform Target. My Platform Target was set to 'Any CPU'.